# How to do header based routing with AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, devops, aws-api-gateway, load-balancing

I have a use case where I would forward request to specific target groups or EC2 instances based on Headers of an incoming request how can I achieve the same with API gateway

We are trying to use Custom Lambda function to address header based routing along with API gateway but it is giving us not a full response code picture.